# How to start Chrome's T-rex game from an Android tablet?

Tags: chrome-for-android, tablet

I can't start Chrome's cute endless T-rex running game from an Android tablet. On a PC, pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> starts the game while for an Android phone, I can just tap the dino to start it. But I can't figure out how to do the same on an Android tablet!

I've tried tapping, holding, swyping, and what not but the game doesn't start.

So, How do I start the T-rex game from an Android tablet?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can connect a physical keyboard and press space to start it, but I don't have a keyboard to test it currently and so, I'd appreciate it if anyone could verify this and post an answer.

Comment: are you sure , that youre running chrome's latest update?

Comment: Yup. Version 56.0.2924.87 now and Play Store says its fully updated.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to install a third-party app called [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard&hl=en).

Then, enable the keyboard and set it as the current input method. Also, check the box against the 'Use permanent notification' setting under 'Input mode settings' in the Hacker's Keyboard settings.

Now, open Chrome and make the dino appear by, say, by enabling airplane mode and visiting any website. Tap on the permanent notification of Hacker's keyboard and press <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Voilà! The game will start. Press <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>↑</kbd>(Up arrow key) to jump. Oh, and Enjoy! :-)